# iOS app to read excel files and pdf

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, filereader

I am relatively new to iOS dev, and wanted to ask the community for guidance, links or hints on how apps that read files are made and from where to start( I want to practice this part but didnt find tutorials on it).

Comment: take a look at UIWebView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `QLPreviewController` for displaying excel and PDF files

Comment: Thanks I will look at it immediately.

Comment: I was searching for hints and guidance for I/O and excel/word/pdf display and read functionality in the context of iOS development.